# Two same URLs in View Result Tree Listener of JMeter when inserted a '/' for sub-urls. Why?

Tags: jmeter, listener

I have used the Listener 'View Results Tree' for testing thetestingworld.com(Home) using JMeter. It displays two same requests for all the requests(sub-urls) other than Main URL(Home) in HTTP Requests. I had put a '/' after all the sub-urls when running the test. But when removed the '/' it shows only one request. See the screenshot.

1. Could you tell the reason why a '/' created two same requests?
2. Is it a good practice to insert '/' in URLs run?

**Two Same Requests Using / slash**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `URL forwarding`.`//` redirects to `/` as shown in this image - so you see 2 requests.

The first request's response header contains the updated Location where it should redirect.  So, You could remove the additional `/` from the test plan as it could affect your test results.

[image]